# MYSQL Copying One Table to Another Table With Conversion of Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, etl

I'm copying data from one database table to another database table.  This essentially is copying the data from our old format to our new format.  So, in addition to simply copying columns value-for-value, I also need to do some conversions in the copy statements as well.

For, example, here is what I have to do the copying...

```
INSERT INTO new_database.table1 (id, product, is_default) 
SELECT id, product, is_default FROM old_database.table1
```

The id and the product are working fine. But, in this example, the old_database stored "is_default" as a `VARCHAR(1)`, either 'Y' or 'N'.  The new_database stores "is_default" as a `BOOLEAN`.

How can I do the conversion between formats within the INSERT SELECT statement I'm already using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below:

```
INSERT INTO new_database.table1 (id, product, is_default) 
SELECT id, product, IF(is_default='Y',1,0) as isdefault FROM old_database.table1
```